# return a type from a function callback using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a function in Kotlin returning a Boolean. The result of the function depends on the result of a call to an external SDK which has 2 callbacks (onSuccess() and onError()).
I do not want to use Kotlin coroutines, CountdownLatch or RxJava, so those answers will not be accepted.
I would like to get some hints/optimizations/corrections using CompletableFuture or Future approach which does not block the main thread of Android application, so the user experience is flawless.
Please check my current implementation:

```
override fun isConnected(): Boolean {
    val sdk = TheSDK.getInstance()
    val executor: Executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
    val completableFutureResult: CompletableFuture<Boolean> = CompletableFuture()
    val completableFuture: CompletableFuture<Void> = CompletableFuture.runAsync(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                sdk.getVersion(object : TwoParamsCallback<TypeWrapper<String>, String> {
                    override fun onSuccess(value: TypeWrapper<String>) {
                        completableFutureResult.complete(true)
                    }

                    override fun onError(error: String) {
                        completableFutureResult.complete(false)
                    }
                })
            }

        }, executor)
    completableFuture.get()
    return completableFutureResult.get()
}
```

where:

```
class TypeWrapper<T>(var returnType: T?)
```

and:

```
interface TwoParamsCallback<Any, E> {
    fun onSuccess(value: Any)
    fun onError(error: E)
}
```

and nevertheless, the final usage in some parts of the app:

```
if (isConnected()) {
  //logic here
}
```

Comment: The way you use the `Executor` is odd. Since it is scoped to the function, you don't really take advantage of the pooling. Also looking at the doc "The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown". All in all I think that the `executor` should be moved out of the function.

Comment: Could you add an answer in code of how you would do it?

Comment: Just pull it out of your function. The executor could be a class instance variable, or referenced from a singleton object. In all these cases the same threadpool would be shared by multiple invocations of isConnected.